# Convert all values of a Record to a new Record in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, record, data-conversion

I have a problem in Typescript, I cannot get a Record object from another.

```js
function numberToString<Keys extends string>(record: Record<Keys, number>): Record<Keys, string> {
    // Convert 
}

// Example
const record: Record<"A" | "B", number> = {
    "A": 10, "B": 20
};

const record2 = numberToString(record) /* {
    "A": "10", "B": "20"
} */
```

As the keys of the object are not definable, it seems impossible to directly create a new Record object, since it is impossible to declare all of its values.
This is why I am asking you how to go about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correctly understood, you want to stringify all numbers.
Here is how you can do it:

```js
type ConvertNumberToString<T extends Record<string, number>> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: `${T[Prop]}`
}

function numberToString<
    Keys extends string,
    Values extends number,
    Obj extends Record<Keys, Values>
>
    (record: Obj): ConvertNumberToString<Obj>
function numberToString<
    Keys extends string,
    Values extends number,
    Obj extends Record<Keys, Values>
>
    (record: Obj) {
    return (Object.keys(record) as Keys[])
        .reduce((acc, elem) => ({
            ...acc,
            [elem]: `${record[elem]}`
        }), {} as Record<Keys, string>)
}


const record = numberToString({ "A": 10, "B": 20 })

const a = record.A // '10'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwG4QE7AHIFcC2AjNAFTgGVhUBLBAcwB5CoIAPYCBAEwGcoAlCAYzip2tTuSrUANFAS4CqAHwKoAXigBvAFBQdUANoAFVHDBQqUANYQQcAGZRCAXQBcUAAYASdYUPGwjgF83TQDNTVssBH5gCkQZOSJScRpabV0AaWtuZlYObjFKGkk0nQA1AEMAGywIbJY2Lnj8NGLdKAB5PAArRnq83gEhEUyQTmkK6tqFTWm2gApUQeFXTq6ASld4ZDRMBNRiMkK6VemIqJi42Wb9pKPUtpG63MaCiVbdCZqnhu4r+XedKtes9uHxBMJaI9xlUvtNZroFkt2CtumsNCUoItgFhUAgoHNVgJgAA6KyjRHg9ho8rcR56RxrDFtYmLdhYfgQOZzcr8fjSCCVCA4NEqZRzLRtSW6Ykynl8plS-QCoUudxeRaUvTKnCBYKKqABNbSdQBKA0gaUyFZaSvGgKRmhMKCBBiTFI1RNeQHZLUcVQABEAEF-a4AIwABmk-oAQiGoAAmcMGxmaZ2u8oejVDYmBqAAejzUAA5BGi0A)

`${T[Prop]}` is a special syntax which allows you to stringify number

Comment: After experimentation, it seems that you forgot to convert the values, you only offered a typing conversion. I'm sorry to bother you again but how to go about it?

Comment: @Storm7953 My bad. Fixed